# What is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha t} \cos[t + y]}{1+\beta e^{-2\alpha t} } dt$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to compute the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha t} \cos[t + y]}{1+\beta e^{-2\alpha t} } dt$

with $\alpha, \beta, c$ real constants, and $\alpha>0,\beta=0$. 
Mathematica was unable to give a solution.

Attempt:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha t} \cos[t + y]}{1+\beta e^{-2\alpha t} } dt = 
\frac{1}{2i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha t} (e^{i(t+y)} - e^{-i(t+y)})}{1+\beta e^{-2\alpha t} } dt =
 \frac{e^{iy}}{2i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{it} - e^{-it})}{e^{\alpha t} +\beta e^{-\alpha t} } dt = 
 \frac{e^{iy}}{2i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{it}}{e^{\alpha t} +\beta e^{-\alpha t} } dt -  \frac{e^{iy}}{2i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-it}}{e^{\alpha t} -\beta e^{-\alpha t} } dt$

Comment: Mathematica computes it. Also, you can set a context via "$\text{\$Assumptions}=\{\alpha>0,\alpha\in\text{Reals},\beta\in\text{Reals},y \in\text{Reals}\};$", just browse the help for "$\text{\$Assumptions}$".

Comment: @Nick: Mathematica still gives the same expression (unevaluated integral) after I add the assumptions.

Comment: Then your Mathematica doens't like you. If you don't expect people to care enough about your ugly question here, you can go to SE Mathematica and let them help you with your code/evaluation :)

Comment: Ah, solved the problem in Mathematica. The answer is indeed in terms of Hypergeometric functions...

Comment: For $\beta=1$ we have the beautiful result $~I=\dfrac\pi{2|a|}\cdot\text{sech}\dfrac\pi{2|a|}\cdot\cos y$.